Does the same rule apply to time clauses and conditional sentences?
Time clauses

When I painted the picture she started laughing said that it was ugly- meaning during paiting she started laughing

When I had painted the picture she started laughing and said that it was ugly- I used past perfect and now the meaning is different, After I was done painting and the picture was done she thought that it was ugly


Does the same rule apply not only to time claues but also to conditinal senteces?

If I paint a picture she will say it is ugly- during the time I am painting

If I have painted the picture/ finish painting the picture she will say it is ugly - after I am done with painting



Your first example is not valid English. Is it missing an and?

What rule are you asking about?

Your gloss of what sentence #1 means is incorrect.  Or are you telling us what idea you would like to express?

@PaulTanenbaum What is the OP asking about? Apparently what every visitor whose username is a firstname has been asking about recently:  when + an atelic verb and the aspect of completion.

Please use a spellchecker. If you care about speaking and writing English well spelling words correctly should be on your list.

This question is similar to: When I had watched TV. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Quite apart from the missing and, sentence 1 is not natural. You would say

When/while I was painting the picture...

Your second sentence 1 would be assumed to mean that she said it was ugly after you had finished it. The second sentence 2 is unnatural for the same reason; if you report a comment on a painting, a finished work is implied unless you specify that it was made while the painting was in progress.

If you watch a movie I will join you- during the movie. If you watch a movie you will tell me the plot- after watchig and we don't need to change anything because it is obvious you need to finish watching before telling the plot?

And likewise, I would assume that the speaker was going to join their friend at the start of the film unless they specified something like "as soon as I can get there" or "when I've finished cleaning the car".

What about something less obvious? For example "If you clean the leaves in the garden I will make you dinner" During cleaning I make dinner or I will make dinner as a reward after  the garden is cleaned. Do we need more context to judge?

Common sense suggests that it's a reward. It doesn't make any difference whether the speaker starts cooking while the leaf-clearing is in progress, but, again, to specify that they do so you need the continuous tense.
